# Problem with react native expo MapView on Android

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo, crash, maps

The app is running fine when i run it in expo go but when i try to use the apk build it will run fine as long as i dont touch the map component. As soon as i touch the button that opens the map component the app crashes

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "supplychain",
    "slug": "supplychain",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.bilalarshad666.supplychain",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "My-Key"
        }
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "0777bd8f-04a1-4775-935e-499953867ec8"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Error Message on Android**
java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@234414038@23.44.14 (190400-0):108)

Comment: Hello! The error clearly says, "API key not found", did you make sure that you have included one for your release build in Android?